# Is there a cross platform, cross browser keyword I can use that refers to the system font?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a cross platform. cross browser keyword I can use that will refer to the users system font in CSS?

Apple provides a `-apple-system` that refers to the operating system font.

```
.myStyle {
    font-family: -apple-system; /* works on OSX */
    font-family: -system;
}
```

More info:
[Using the system font in web content](https://webkit.org/blog/3709/using-the-system-font-in-web-content/)
[System fonts](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Jul/0169.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Not in my knowledge but there is a solution

```
/* System Fonts as used by GitHub */
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", sans-serif;
}
```

or

```
/* Define the "system" font family */
@font-face {
  font-family: system;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local(".SFNSText-Light"), local(".HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Light"), local(".LucidaGrandeUI"), local("Ubuntu Light"), local("Segoe UI Light"), local("Roboto-Light"), local("DroidSans"), local("Tahoma");
}

/* Now, let's apply it on an element */
body {
  font-family: "system";
}
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/system-font-stack/

Answer (score 2):

For chrome and safari there is `font-family: system-ui`.[1](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5640395337760768)